# LSTM InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, embedding

I'm trying to implement both character and word lstms but i keep getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[310,0] = 119 is not in [0, 119)
     [[node model_3/time_distributed_12/embedding_7/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-64-51f6ad92087d>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_28785]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_3/time_distributed_12/embedding_7/embedding_lookup:
 model_3/time_distributed_12/embedding_7/embedding_lookup/24179
```

This is my model:

```
# input and embedding for words
word_in = Input(shape=(max_len,))
emb_word = embedding_layer(word_in)

# input and embeddings for characters
char_in = Input(shape=(max_len, max_len_char,)) 
emb_char = Embedding(input_dim=n_chars + 1, output_dim=20, 
                           input_length=max_len_char, mask_zero=True)
print(emb_char)
char_dist = TimeDistributed(emb_char)(char_in)
# character LSTM to get word encodings by characters
char_enc = TimeDistributed(LSTM(units=20, return_sequences=False,
                                recurrent_dropout=0.5))(char_dist)

# main LSTM

x = concatenate([emb_word, char_enc])

x = SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(x)
main_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False,recurrent_dropout=0.6))(x)
out = Dense(num_of_classes, activation="sigmoid")(main_lstm)


model = Model([word_in, char_in], out)
```

I've read that it is to do with the input. My X_char_tr shape is `(2770, 10, 30)` X_word_tr.shape is `(2770, 10)`  and y_tr is `(2770,135)`

```
history = model.fit([X_word_tr,
                    (np.array(X_char_tr)).astype('float32').reshape((len(X_char_tr), max_len, max_len_char))],
                    np.array(to_categorical(y_tr)), epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

This is my word embedding layer:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(
    vocab_size + 1,
    config['W2V_DIM'],
    weights=[w2v_weights],
    input_length=max_sequence_len,
    trainable=False
)
```

The word vector shape is (n_words,128)

Answer (score 1):

Check X_char_tr. As far as I understand - vocabulary size (n_char) is 118. So maximum permitted value for this tensor is 118. But the first value is 119.

Try this:

```
print(tf.where(X_char_tr>118))
```

Comment: Yes, thats the number of unique characters n_chars i have. Should the input_dim for char embedding be something else?

Comment: What is X_char_tr[0][0][0] ? Is it 119 ?

Comment: No, 38. This is  `X_char_tr[0][0]`:

`array([ 38,  79, 115,  61,  46,  55,  61,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0])`

Comment: I get this `tf.Tensor([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64) `, but not sure what that means. First timei ran it, it complained about NoneTypes inside the array so i has to convert them to floats

Comment: it means that your X_char_tr has no elements exceeding 118. So it is correct. Please add code of embedding_layer() to the question